# Simple 'New Post' WordPress email notification plugin?

Tags: web-development, wordpress

I'm setting up a WordPress site with a very simple subscribe feature. I don't want newsletters or anything fancy like that, I just want visitors to be able to enter their email address and automatically receive an email whenever a new blog post is posted, and be able to unsubscribe if they want.

This has proven to be a shockingly difficult feature to find in a plugin. There are plenty for newsletters but very few for blog updates, and the ones that I did find have terrible designs or functionality.

Does anyone know of any simple, lightweight, functional plugins that can accomplish this?

I've found a few duplicate questions here on WordPress Stack Exchange, but the answers point to old plugins that sadly don't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Jetpack](https://jetpack.me/)'s [Subscription module](https://jetpack.me/support/subscriptions/) for this purpose.

Jetpack does a lot more than this, but because it's extremely modular, I still consider it lightweight. Because it's built by a dedicated team of WordPress pros, it also stands a good chance of being around for the long haul.

Comment: I've actually had this recommended before - but I find it highly dubious, annoying, and extraneous to be forced to log in and connect to a WordPress account just to use the dang plugin. Especially when this is a client project and I won't want this plugin connected to MY WordPress, so I need to make another account just to use the plugin.

Comment: Fair enough. We routinely set up WordPress.com accounts for our clients as part of our build process, and it's a hassle, but worth it to me because of the value we get from Jetpack (we use a number of its features on most sites).